# Selecting decimal numbers from XML that use a comma as the decimal separator

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am trying to select values out of an XML document and some are decimal values but they are in the XML data feed separated by a comma instead of a decimal point `2,05` instead of `2.05`. I believe this is the German style of writing decimal numbers.

Anyway, I get an error `Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric` when I try to select them and was hoping there was some way to make this query work without having to do preprocessing on the source data:

```
DECLARE @XmlDoc INT
DECLARE @XmlData VARCHAR(MAX) 

SET @XmlData = '<xml><sample><decvalue>2,05</decvalue></sample></xml>'

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @XmlDoc OUTPUT, @XmlData

SELECT *
FROM OPENXML(@XmlDoc,'/xml/sample',2)                     
WITH (decvalue DECIMAL(10,2) 'decvalue')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one -

**Query:**

```
DECLARE @XmlData XML 
SELECT @XmlData = '<xml><sample><decvalue>2,05</decvalue></sample></xml>'

SELECT CAST(REPLACE(t.c.value('decvalue[1]', 'VARCHAR(10)'), ',', '.') AS DECIMAL(10,2))
FROM @XmlData.nodes('/xml/sample') t(c)
```

**Output:**

```
2.05
```

Comment: And also, if after run `sp_xml_preparedocument`, you don't call `sp_xml_removedocument`, may occur a memory leak on server.

Comment: This does the trick. I was just adapting it to my actual query (many more columns). I thought at first it might get a bit messy but it is actually quite clean. Thanks!